# Extraer href desde una tabla mediante PHP

Tags: php, dom

Deseo extraer desde una tabla en una Página Web el contenido de ésta mas la referencia que tiene cada una de ellas, ya extraigo la tabla pero me falta el como llegar al tag `href`, me pueden ayudar?.

Esta es la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código usado es el siguiente:

```
$tabla = $html->getElementsByTagName("table")->item(1);

foreach($tabla->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr) {

$tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td'); // get the columns in this row

$href =  $tr->getElementsByTagName('a'); //->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
if (trim($tds->item(0)->nodeValue) <> '') {

    echo $tds->item(0)->nodeValue." , ".
         $tds->item(1)->nodeValue." , ".
         $tds->item(1)->nodeValue." , ".
         $tds->item(3)->nodeValue." , ".
         $tds->item(4)->nodeValue." , ".
         $tds->item(5)->nodeValue." , ".
         $tds->item(6)->nodeValue." , ".
         $tds->item(7)->nodeValue." , ".
         $tds->item(8)->nodeValue." , ";
        //$href;

    echo "<br />";   
}
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Ulises

Gracias a todos por sus respuestas, las he implementado pero me arroja error, para mejor claridad dispongo todo el código, si lo ejecutan sale el error que muestro más abajo:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $html = new DomDocument;
    $source = file_get_contents("http://seia.sea.gob.cl/busqueda/buscarProyectoAction.php?nombre=central&_paginador_refresh=0&_paginador_fila_actual=2");

    $html->loadHTML($source);

    // Cada TR

    $tabla = $html->getElementsByTagName("table")->item(1);

    foreach($tabla->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr)
    {
        $tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td'); // get the columns in this row

        //$href = $tds->getAttribute('href');

        $href = $tds->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href'‌​);

        if (trim($tds->item(0)->nodeValue) <> '') {

            echo $tds->item(0)->nodeValue." , ".
                 $tds->item(1)->nodeValue." , ".
                 $tds->item(1)->nodeValue." , ".
                 $tds->item(3)->nodeValue." , ".
                 $tds->item(4)->nodeValue." , ".
                 $tds->item(5)->nodeValue." , ".
                 $tds->item(6)->nodeValue." , ".
                 $tds->item(7)->nodeValue." , ".
                 $tds->item(8)->nodeValue." , ";
                 //$href;

            echo "<br />";   
        } 

        //break; // don't check any further rows

    }
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has intentado obtenerlo usando [`getAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/es/domelement.getattribute.php)? Ejemplo: `$tr->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');`

Comment: Hola J. Castro, gracias por tu espuesta, efectivamente lo he intentado pero al poner esa instrucción no me arroja nada, es como si hubiera un "error" pero no dice cual.

Comment: Por favor, [edita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/42540/edit) tu pregunta y agrega el error completo que obtienes. También seria de mucha utilidad si pudieras agregar el `HTML` que intentas leer.

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, básicamente el primer elemento de la tabla es la cabezera, al no tener ´<a>´ sobre dicho elemento, no puedes hacer item(0) sobre null

Comment: No puedes aprobar la respuesta? En lo que se pueda ayudar aqui estamos

Comment: @urivera_cl Acepta la respuesta correcta si se ha resuelto tu problema para que se cierre el ciclo de esta pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: El problema que tienes es de sintaxis. Cambia la línea que pone `$href = $tds->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href'<200c><200b>);` y pon simplemente `$href = $tds->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');`. PD: Ten cuidado con lo que copias/pegas, hay editores que te ocultan el contenido real de lo que has pegado en el código.

Answer (score 1):

```
$href = array();
foreach ($tds as $td) {
    $href [] = $td->getAttribute('href ');
}
```

o

```
 $href = $tds[0]->getAttribute('href ');
```

El primer ejemplo seria en el caso de que necesitaras extraer el href de mas de un td, en ese ejemplo recorre todos los td y guarda en un array lodos los href de esta manera:

```
$ref[0]=href1; 
$ref[1]=href2; 
$ref[2]=href3; 
$ref[3]=href4;
```

y la segunda te accederias directamente al atributo href del primer td.

Gracias por tu respuesta,

implementé tu respuesta pero me arroja el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute()

Comment: Este sitio trata de dar respuestas y explciarlas. A veces no basta con poner un fragmento de código, es mejor explicarlo también, sobretodo si das mas de una solución. ¿Podrías decir las diferencias entre ellas con sus ventajas y desventajas?

Comment: Mil disculpas, soy nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Yo hice esto, y si funciona

```
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="http://localhost"/></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

$var = new DOMDocument();
$var->loadHTML($html);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($var->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href'));
echo '</pre>';
```

y el resultado es

```
http://localhost
```

La razon por la que te marca error es porque al obtener tus elementos `<a>`

```
$a = $tr->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

debes verificar que al menos haya alguno sobre tus datos

```
if($a->length > 0){
    $href = $a->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
}
```

o puedes realizar una iteración, y remueve el `break` al final de tu ciclo, ya que dicha tabla obtiene el primer `tr` como la cabezera y alli no hay ningun `<a>`, al no poder obtener `item(0)` no puede ejecutar `getAttribute` sobre `null`, por eso el error

Excelente...!!!! funcionó a la perfección.. Gracias...